# Struts 2.5 to Struts 2.5.33 upgrade issue

Tags: java

```
21-Mar-24 18:42:32 [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext 220]  ERROR: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginAction' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) ~[org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) ~[org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) ~[org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.comviva.im.ui.oam.OamMonitor.contextInitialized(OamMonitor.java:101) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4462) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4914) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_381]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_381]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.83]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112) [?:1.8.0_381]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_381]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.83]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [?:1.8.0_381]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.83]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.createEnhancer(Cglib2AopProxy.java:228) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:170) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.createEnhancer(Cglib2AopProxy.java:228) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:170) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2337) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:810) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.83]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassVisitor(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73) ~[cglib-3.2.6.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.createEnhancer(Cglib2AopProxy.java:228) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:170) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322) ~[org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 53 more
```

I'm trying to upgrade struts 2.5 -> 2.5.33. I'm facing incompatible library issue with cglib-3.3.0.jar and org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar